# Android API 19 WebView Screen Density

Tags: java, android, webview

I am working on updating my app to target API 19. It uses webview inside of a fragment. For some reason on devices running Android 4.4.2 the website is loaded so small it is unreadable. It appears to me that the screen doubles in density. I have been looking for documentation on why this is happening but I have not found any. It works fine in devices running Jellybean and below. Below is a sample of the javascript I am using in the webview.

```
public static void javascript(WebView view, String url) {
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){
        //KitKat and above
        view.evaluateJavascript("var con = document.getElementById('header_container').style.display='none';",null);
} else{
        // Jellybean and below
        view.loadUrl("javascript:var con = document.getElementById('header_container').style.display='none';"
}
}
```

Comment: What's that Java/JS code got to do with it?

Comment: I just commented it all out and it makes no difference. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

I used this to fix it.

```
view.evaluateJavascript("document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.zoom = '200%'; ", null);
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do this. Can you share your webview configuration options and the viewport meta tag you are using?